# grok filter for log pattern

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash-grok

I have a log pattern which is this form.

```
field1|field2|field3|field4|field5| key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3
```

key value pair can some in any order. key2 may be earlier that key1.

I am able to parse the field1-field5. BUt not sure how to do it for key value pairs

```
%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue1}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue2}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue3}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue4}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue5}\|
```

Can I create a map of key-value in `grok` and then send specific keys ???
Any advise ?

Comment: If there are always 3 key-value pairs, you can just add 3 `\s*(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)`: try `%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue1}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue2}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue3}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue4}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue5}\|\s*(?<key>\w+)=(?<value>\w+)\s*(?<key1>\w+)=(?<value1>\w+)\s*(?<key2>\w+)=(?<value2>\w+)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use kv filter to parse other part. Like:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue1}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue2}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue3}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue4}\|%{GREEDYDATA:fieldValue5}\| %{GREEDYDATA:keyValue}" }
 }
kv {
    source => "keyValue"
}
```

Comment: Thanks alpert. Perfect ..!!